# I cant get distinct member ids from this SQLalchemy code snippet

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this big SQLalchemy code snippet:

```
        teamIds = db.session.query(TeamMemberLinkModel.teamId).filter(TeamMemberLinkModel.memberId == memberId)

        projectQuery = db.session.query(ProjectModel.name,
                                        ProjectModel.isActive,
                                        select(func.array_agg(
                                            func.json_build_object(
                                                'teamId', ProjectTeamLinkModel.teamId,
                                                'teamName', ProjectTeamLinkModel.teamName,
                                                'colorCode', ProjectTeamLinkModel.colorCode
                                            )
                                        )).where(ProjectTeamLinkModel.teamId.in_(teamIds),
                                                 ProjectTeamLinkModel.projectId == ProjectModel.id).label('teams'),
                                        ProjectModel.id,
                                        ProjectModel.clientId,
                                        select(func.array_agg(
                                            func.json_build_object(
                                                'memberName', TeamMemberLinkModel.memberName,
                                                'memberId', TeamMemberLinkModel.memberId,
                                                'roleId', TeamMemberLinkModel.roleId,
                                                'roleName', TeamMemberLinkModel.roleName
                                            )
                                        )).label(
                                            'members'),
                                        ProjectModel.isDeleted,
                                        func.json_build_object(
                                            'id', ProjectModel.clientId,
                                            'name', ProjectModel.clientName
                                        ).label('client')).filter(ProjectModel.id.in_(unionQuery),
                                                                  ProjectModel.isDeleted.is_(False))
```

for each project, i correctly get the name,id,teams,etc. but the thing is that for each project i get in the list (the return looks like `[o for o in projectQuery]` for example), the members list is always full with all the members in the database and there are duplicates too. Is there a way to get the members to belong to the corresponding teams found in the teams list and for the duplicates to also be removed?

ProjectModel:

```
    serialize_only = ('id', 'name', 'isActive', 'client.id', 'client.name',
                      'teams.teamId', 'teams.teamName', 'teams.colorCode', 'members.memberId', 'members.memberName',
                      'members.roleId', 'members.roleName', 'members.isOtherResource', 'members.avatar')

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    isActive = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    isDeleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, server_default="false")
    clientId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("client.id"), nullable=False)
    client = db.relationship('ClientModel', back_populates='projects')
    companyId = column_property(select(ClientModel.companyId).where(ClientModel.id == clientId).as_scalar())
    clientName = column_property(select(ClientModel.name).where(ClientModel.id == clientId).as_scalar())
```

TeamMemberLinkModel:

```
    serialize_only = ('memberId', 'memberName', 'memberEmail', 'memberAvatar', 'roleId', 'roleName')
    callbacks = {}

    memberId = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('employee.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),  primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    roleId = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('employee-role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    teamId = db.Column(db.BigInteger,  db.ForeignKey('team.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    isLeader = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False, server_default="false")
    memberName = column_property(select(UserModel.name).where(UserModel.id == memberId).as_scalar())
    memberEmail = column_property(select(UserModel.email).where(UserModel.id == memberId).as_scalar())
    memberAvatar = column_property(select(UserModel.avatar).where(UserModel.id == memberId).as_scalar())
    roleName = column_property(select(EmployeeRoleModel.name).where(EmployeeRoleModel.id == roleId).as_scalar())

    employee = db.relationship('EmployeeModel', foreign_keys=[memberId],
                               backref=backref('_teams', lazy='dynamic', cascade="delete, delete-orphan"))
    team = db.relationship('TeamModel', backref=backref('_members', cascade="delete, delete-orphan"))
    role = db.relationship('EmployeeRoleModel', backref=backref('_links', cascade="delete, delete-orphan"))
```

ProjectTeamLinkModel:

```
    projectId = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('project.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
    teamId = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('team.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
    teamName = column_property(select(TeamModel.name).where(TeamModel.id == teamId).as_scalar())
    colorCode = column_property(select(TeamModel.colorCode).where(TeamModel.id == teamId).as_scalar())

    team = db.relationship('TeamModel', backref=backref('projects', cascade="all,delete"))
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are building the JSON in the query instead of just using a serializer after you get the objects back ?

Comment: It was the first thing I tried and worked. Honestly, all because of that. Even if i tried to change it, i don't know how to put the conditions in the WHERE / FILTER statements to get what i want.

Comment: I think instead of using all these `column_property`s you should just use loader options to load in the relationships you want.  Do you know about those?  I guess I'm not sure why you are using so many of the properties because they make reasoning about the queries very difficult and should be used sparingly.